# Get Values in GridView textbox TemplateField

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, findcontrol

I have an asp.net page called Default.aspx, and it's master page is Site.master. In the Default.aspx, i added a gridview with 3 databound fields and 1 Templatefield, and then, dragged a TextBox inside this templatefield.

[image: Image Templatefield Editor]

I'm trying to get the textbox values for each row in this gridview, using the FindControl method, but it's returning Nothing.

Here is the code that i'm using to retrieve these values:

```
For Each gvr As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

        Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(gvr.FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
        Dim txt As String = tb.Text
        MsgBox(txt)

    Next
```

Note: I'm using masterPages, and i'm thinking this is causing the problem.

[edit]

In the Page_load event, to bound the gridview, i'm using the code:

```
        GridView1.DataSource = f.xDa
        GridView1.DataBind()
```

In the Button1, I've added the code:

```
For Each gvr As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

        Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(gvr.FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
        Dim txt As String = tb.Text
        MsgBox(txt)

    Next
```

But i'm Always getting an empty textbox.

Thank's everybody!

Comment: Where are you calling that code?  If the GridView isn't databound yet, there probably won't be anything to show.  Also, does that code throw an error, or do you just get an empty string in the MsgBox?

Comment: Yes, the Gridview works fine, with the code:

GridView1.DataSource = f.xDa
        GridView1.DataBind()

But, when i type inside the textboxes, i cant get the values inside them.... In this case, i'm getting an empty string in the msgbox.

Comment: Inside what event is the code in your question executed?

Comment: In the Page_Load:
 GridView1.DataSource = f.xDa GridView1.DataBind()

In a Button called Button1 i put the code:
<code>  

        For Each gvr As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

        Dim tb As TextBox = DirectCast(gvr.FindControl("TextBox1"), TextBox)
        Dim txt As String = tb.Text
        MsgBox(txt)

    Next
<code>

Comment: Please use the "edit" button to update your question with the relevant code.  It's too hard to comprehend in the comments here =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update your `Page_Load` code to this:

```
If Not IsPostBack Then
    GridView1.DataSource = f.xDa
    GridView1.DataBind()
End If
```

By the time your code gets to the `Button_Click` event, it has already repopulated the GridView with data from your database (overwriting what your user typed into the TextBox).

The code I've added above causes the data to be loaded only the first time - then the ASP.NET viewstate handles making sure the state of the GridView is kept up-to-date.

Comment: Hey man, yoy saved my day!!!
It worked fine!!
Hey @jadarnel27
How can i post an expressive thank to your post? Im new here!!

Comment: @DiegoOliveira The comment, upvote, and accept is plenty of thanks =)  I'm glad I was able to help you.  I'd say when you are able, "pay it forward" by contributing good answers to the site as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but my gridview wasn't rendered at Page_Load so I couldn't add the "If Not IsPostBack" bindings to the Page_Load as the SQL dataset I was using wasn't yet declared.

Instead of the FindControl and calling your textbox by name, trying something like this might work if you can't use the Page_Load gridview databinding:

```
For Each gvr As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows

    Dim txt As String = CType(gvr.Cells(0).Controls(0), TextBox).Text
    MsgBox(txt)

Next
```

The (0) in the Cells(0) is the column number in your gridview that you are trying to access. So for example If "TextBox1" is the 1st column use Cells(0),  if it is the 2nd column use Cells(1) and so on. This allows the text in the textbox to be retrieved without having to add an additional section in the Page_Load