# Textbox values retrieving null in code behind asp.net c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a `GriView` which contains `ItemTemplates` but I'm not able to retrieve values in code behind. I'm getting `null` value in `TextBox`.
here is my aspx code:

```aspx
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridview" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="1100px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="600px" >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Refine Requirement " HeaderStyle-Width="200px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ForeColor="Black" Height="27px" Width="200px" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle Width="200px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reason">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="REASON" TextMode="MultiLine" ForeColor="Black" Font-Size="Medium" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
 <asp:Button ID="ButtonInsert"  runat="server" ForeColor="White" BorderColor="White" OnClick="get" BorderStyle="Double" BackColor="#990000"  Text="Submit All Requirements" style="position:relative; left:400px;" />
```

and here is my code behind :

```
public void get(object o,EventArgs e)
{
foreach (GridViewRow gvr in gridview.Rows)
{
    TextBox txtAmount = gvr.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox;
    string s = txtAmount.Text;
}
}
```

but I'm getting `null` value in `s`.

Comment: but txtamount is not null right?

Comment: in which grid event are you doing this?

Comment: yes @Mysterio11.I enter value in `textbox` but it giving me `null` value

Comment: @NikhilVartak kindly check my updated question now.I'm using on `button` click

Comment: In `gridview` i have some `columns` which getting values from `database` by bind data using `Eval` .`eval` working fine,it's ` retrieving` values but not working for `textbox`

Comment: Forget to not rebind on postback maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19145323/get-values-in-gridview-textbox-templatefield

Answer (score 0):

If you using any function for retrieving the grid view from database and calling it in page_Load() event then it may cause this issue. try to call this function in page_LoadComplete() event and it will work.